# Can we integrate selenium with JIRA and HP ALM?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, jira, hp-alm

We would like to automate regression test cases using selenium.These regression test cases are availbale in JIRA and HP ALM.My Objective here is to use Selenium(Java) and Automate these test cases in such a way that when I execute individual test cases from selenium webdriver through eclipse IDE, my test cases should be able to mark results (Pass/Fail) corresponding to each test case. Can you please let me know if this can be done??

Comment: jira as a ticket system or as a repo?

Comment: Have you tried the available plugins in Marketplace?

Comment: You need https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/cloud/ and http://alm-help.saas.hpe.com/en/12.20/api_refs/REST_TECH_PREVIEW/ALM_REST_API_TP.html

Comment: you may be able to reach the browsable version of the api via your web broswer `yourserver/plugins/servlet/restbrowser#/` for jira

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at [Agiletestware Bumblebee](http://www.agiletestware.com/bumblebee) which has a Java annotations package and JUnit test listener, so you can use it to send test results to HP ALM if you use selenium together with JUnit or TestNG

Please refer to: http://www.agiletestware.com/docs/bumblebee-docs/en/latest/qa-frameworks/junit/

Disclaimer: I'm a developer of Bumblebee.

Comment: I've went through your tutorial, and I was curios to see if is there any way to link your tests to an existent test case from HP ALM. Thanks!

Comment: @Razvan Yes, this is possible via Java annotations, there is 'almid' attribute of Bumblebee annotation which can contain an ID of an existing ALM test. Please refer to the docs for details: https://www.agiletestware.com/docs/bumblebee-docs/en/latest/qa-frameworks/testng/#map-testng-test-method-to-existing-test-in-hp-alm

Comment: I have ALM v.12 and I don't have that TS_USER_01 field. Only the ID (which is unique and numbers only) and the rest are dropdowns.

Comment: Hmmm, I think there is an incorrect screenshot in the docs, please have a look at the link below for JUnit: https://www.agiletestware.com/docs/bumblebee-docs/en/latest/qa-frameworks/junit/#map-junit-test-method-to-existing-test-in-hp-alm  The thing is to get an ID of your ALM test and put it into almid attribute

Comment: make sense now, looks fine. The last question, is there any integration with Cucumber? Saw something with Serenity, but I need it for Cucumber-TestNG

Comment: Yes, we do support integration with cucumber but it is available via CI plugin (you need to send cucumber JSON reports to Bumblebee server). We haven't tested cucumber with java annotations and I'm not sure it's going to work fine, because AFAIK you have to use a special cucumber runner so our listeners/reporters might not work properly. I think if this is a showstopper for you - our team can have an R&D and see if this is something we can support.